# Anyone know what's the data source of http://logstash.openstack.org?

Tags: logstash, openstack, kibana

I'm new to OpenStack and I'd like to do some mining on OpenStack logs. So I found this webpage: http://logstash.openstack.org
It gives a lot of logs which seems interesting. Anyone know how these data are generated and where they are from?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: [Openstack Jenkins Logstash](http://ci.openstack.org/logstash.html), those are the logs generated from Jenkins test runs. It is tool to check Openstack's packages building process and also showcases how [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) works.

If you are interested on installing something similar, take a look on these three:

- [logstash](http://logstash.net/)
- [kibana.org](http://kibana.org/)
- [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

Comment: Thanks I found that too but it still seems not obvious to me... Is there some machines running OpenStack somewhere constantly testing those packages, and push the logs to that web address?

Comment: Assume the process is as follows: i) developers push code to openstack git ii) the code is accepted through their review system iii) Jenkins poll the git repo for changes every X minutes iv) if changes exist Jenkins builds the executables/distributables and output the progress in logs v) logstash know the location of logs and collects them vi) logstash index the logs' content to its database.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! I spent one day reading this: http://www.joinfu.com/2014/01/understanding-the-openstack-ci-system/  And the process is basically what you summarized.